# How can I compare date time values in a content form?

Tags: forms, 10

I want to use `getString()` instead of `[0]['value']`. How do I do that, if it possible? Is there any other way?

This is the array I get when I run this code.

```php
dump($form_state->getValue('field_start_time'));
dump($form_state->getValue('field_end_time'));
dump($form_state->getValue('field_duration'));
die();
```

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "value" => Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime {#2248 ▼
      #inputTimeRaw: ""
      #inputTimeAdjusted: ""
      #inputTimeZoneRaw: ""
      #inputTimeZoneAdjusted: ""
      #inputFormatRaw: ""
      #inputFormatAdjusted: ""
      #langcode: "en"
      #errors: []
      #dateTimeObject: DateTime @1700800785 {#2247 ▼
        date: 2023-11-24 04:39:45.0 UTC (+00:00)
      }
      #formatTranslationCache: null
      #stringTranslation: null
    }
  ]
]
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "value" => Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime {#2222 ▼
      #inputTimeRaw: ""
      #inputTimeAdjusted: ""
      #inputTimeZoneRaw: ""
      #inputTimeZoneAdjusted: ""
      #inputFormatRaw: ""
      #inputFormatAdjusted: ""
      #langcode: "en"
      #errors: []
      #dateTimeObject: DateTime @1700807985 {#2211 ▼
        date: 2023-11-24 06:39:45.0 UTC (+00:00)
      }
      #formatTranslationCache: null
      #stringTranslation: null
    }
  ]
]
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "duration" => DateInterval {#2340 ▼
      interval: + 02:00:00.0
      +"y": 0
      +"m": 0
      +"d": 0
      +"h": 2
      +"i": 0
      +"s": 0
      +"f": 0.0
      +"weekday": 0
      +"weekday_behavior": 0
      +"first_last_day_of": 0
      +"invert": 0
      +"days": false
      +"special_type": 0
      +"special_amount": 0
      +"have_weekday_relative": 0
      +"have_special_relative": 0
    }
    "seconds" => 7200
  ]
]
```

The code I am using in my module is the following one.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function ir_hiring_validation_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_exam_form' || $form_id == 'node_exam_edit_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'ir_hiring_validation_validate';
  }
}

/**
 * Custom validation callback to check start time, end time, and duration.
 */
function ir_hiring_validation_validate($form, $form_state) {
  $start_time = $form_state->getValue('field_start_time')[0]['value'];
  $end_time = $form_state->getValue('field_end_time')[0]['value'];
  $duration_seconds = $form_state->getValue('field_duration')[0]['seconds'];
  if (strtotime($end_time) < strtotime($start_time)) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('field_end_time', t('End time cannot be less than start time.'));
  }
  elseif (!empty($duration_seconds)) {
    $expected_end_timestamp = strtotime($start_time) + $duration_seconds;
    if (strtotime($end_time) != $expected_end_timestamp) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('field_end_time', t('End time need to same as total time more than exam.'));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a string and strtotime() you could get the timestamp directly via the method getTimeStamp():

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;

...

  if ($start_time instanceof DrupalDateTime && $end_time instanceof DrupalDateTime) {
    if ($end_time->getTimestamp() < $start_time->getTimestamp()) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('field_end_time', t('End time cannot be less than start time.'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: `->getTimeStamp()` gets the value as timestamp. It's a direct replacement for `strtotime()` which also gets a timestamp and in your code example this is the only value you are using. If you want a string for displaying the date use `->format($format)`

Answer (score 0):

`\DateTime` objects are directly comparable without having to resolve them to scalar values.